# get a list of productId-s from in-app apple

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am developing and app, in this case is a newsletter with free and payed subscriptions.
One of best and up to date tutorial can be found [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) it is not 2 min to write 3 line of code and do 2 click and is working.

All tutorials, code examples what I got they are going to iTunnes with hardcoded productId-s in app and asking price and other info.

My questions how can I interrogate apple's servers to get the available productid for my app?

Something like:

```
NSString myBoundleId = getMyBoundleID(); // will return @"com.mycompany.myapp"
NSArray* productIdsInStore = getProductIdsInStore(myBoundleId); // it should return  @"com.mycompany.myapp.product1free", @"com.mycompany.myapp.product2payed1month",@"com.mycompany.myapp.productSomethingNew"
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/

Comment: @Desdenova I haven't found thre anything there related to my question. Restore transcations needs the user to login, I don't want, just get the available productids to an app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this isn't possible in my experience. 
In a similar circumstance I've set #define lines in with the the bundle ids of subscriptions and the prefix for single editions.
Then you can reference them and pattern match but you can;t fetch them from iTunes Connect in the app programatically.

Comment: this is my sad experience too, that is why wanted to check here, maybe have others a solution, thanks